# jenkins pipeline not build remotely

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to build a job by pipeline to my other slave in the master

the pipeline is like this

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label "virtual"
    }
    stages {
        stage("test one") {
            steps {
                echo " test test test"
            }
        }
        stage("test two") {
            steps {
                echo " testttttttttt "
            }
        }
    }
}
```

they syntax not getting the error but it doesn't build on my slave server, 
but when I run on freestyle job by `Restrict where this project can be run` with that label then execute sheel by echo "test test"
it was built on my slave server, 
what is wrong with my pipeline ? do I missing something?

after build

```
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on virtual in /home/virtual/jenkins/workspace/demoo
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (test one)
[Pipeline] echo
 test test test
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (test two)
[Pipeline] echo
 testttttttttt 
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
```

Comment: can you please provide the logs also?

Comment: just edited it, plesse check :) @user_9090

Comment: Its running on the label you have mentioned:-

Running on virtual in /home/virtual/jenkins/workspace/demoo

Comment: how to build it ? but when i check on my server, i didn't see any folder of that job

Comment: when i did freestyle job, and i build it, the name job of that job in that folder /home/virtual/jenkins/workspace/, but if i did with pipeline is not

Comment: workspace location you have to defined in the node configuration

Comment: can u give example please, i am still new for this

Comment: please follow this url :-https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jenkins/jenkins_distributed_builds.htm

Comment: ohh i did create a workspace for that when i connect the node, so the problem it is not show on that folder

Comment: provide some path in node configuration :- "Remote root directory", then build will automatically create workspace

Comment: can u show me example please,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The build works like you did it already. The steps will be executed on the slave. If you add something like `clone a repository` to your step, your workspace directory will be created.

Pipeline and Freestylejobs are working here different. The Freestylejob will make the directory in workspace as soon as it runs at the first time. The Pipelinejob will create the directory as soon as it needs this this directory.

I created a simple Pipeline:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label "linux"
    }
    stages {
        stage("test one") {
            steps {
                sh "echo 'test test test' > text.txt"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I converted your `echo` to a `sh` command because my Slave is a linux slave. The `sh` step creates a text.txt file. As soon as I run this job, the directory will be created:

```
[<user>@<server> test-pipeline]$ pwd
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test-pipeline
[<user>@<server> test-pipeline]$ ls -l
total 4
-rw-r----- 1 <user> <group> 15 Oct  7 16:49 text.txt
```

Comment: how about if we build and deploy every commit on dev ? what syntax should we do

Comment: Sorry, I think I haven't understood your problem. But I think I get it now.

Comment: your code was work, which menu i should use for check commit ? pool scm ? or Build periodically ?? i was tried pool scm every minutes, but nothing build after i change on my git

Comment: If you want to start the build on every commit on a scm, you have to take your pipeline code and add it to a scm like github. Then you can select `Pipeline script from SCM` and select a branch and your job will run whenever somebody will commit something to that branch.

Answer (score 2):

Add the path you want in the **Remote root directory** (yellow column) as shown below:-

[image]

Comment: yes i did it before and , i already  set up my node like that before i run pipeline it, but what i dont know , why it is not on that directory ?